# How to COMPLETELY reset windows vista, leaving only the os

Tags: windows, windows-vista, reset, factory-defaults

How do I completely reset my Windows Vista computer? The only help I can find for this online is for reinstalling from a backup - I don't want to keep any data on the computer, except for Windows Vista itself. I don't have an installation disc - the computer was bought preinstalled with it.

Is it possible to do this?

Please help!

Comment: If you go to your start menu you might be able to search for an option "create recovery media" which might allow you to create a USB stick that combined with your product key will do what you want. Otherwise you should just need to download the media somewhere. Your manufacturer might be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not possible.
The windows installation does not include information that enables you to distinguish between files that belong to the initial installation and everything that came after.

You would need to buy a Vista license that contains the disc and the certificate of authenticity.

Another way, though probably not legal would be to extract the installation code from the installation and just buy installation media that fit to the type of license.

Comment: Please follow the advice of Mokubai. There is at least a possibility of creating recovery media. 
Write down your installation key, your Vista version (including service pack level?) and the language. It may be that the key does not fit every installation disc - you would need to do a little research.

Comment: You could get dubious iso downloads from the internet and install them in a virtual machine to check your installation key compatibility. Once you found the corresponding ones, buy the installation media.
Buying a complete license including media and key appears easier to me. :)